# How rotate and add new variable to end?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to get a list to rotate, add a variable to the end, and the next time the function is called, the list rotates again ect etc. How ever, when I implement this code, the list doesn't rotate every time the function is ran.

```
var1 = "1";
var2 = "2";
var3 = "3";
var4 = "4";
var5 = "5";
check = [var1, var2, var3, var4, var5]

def checkIfExists(checkList):
    var = input();

    if var not in checkList:
        check = checkList[1:] + checkList[:1]
        check.append(var)
        check.pop(1)
        check = checkList[2:] + checkList[:2]
        print(check)
```

its entirely possible I'm just goofing up and messing up somewhere, but I'm stuck. Any help?

Comment: what do you mean by "rotating" a list?

Comment: I'd like the list to move all items to the left once, hence the slicing

Comment: I suggest you pass in var instead of input() this makes it easier to explain the problem.  Then tell us what output you expect from checkIfExists(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"], "6").

Comment: Okay, so I pass in 6 which is not within check[], and expect ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6'] but instead I get ['2', '4', '5', '1', '6'], then when I run the function again with 7, i expect  ['3', '4', '5', '6', '7'] but i get ['2', '4', '5', '1', '7'], so Its not putting the correct number in the correct index and its not rotating everytime the function is called

Comment: My apologies for not making that clearer

Comment: What should the output be if you pass in an empty list?  [].pop(0) will give you an IndexError exception.

Comment: The list will be populated from the start, no chance at an empty list

Answer (score 1):

```py
def checkIfExists(checkList):
    print('Input new number:')
    var = input()
    if var not in checkList:
        check.pop(0)
        check.append(var)
        print('return new check:')
        print(check)
```

test result:

```sh
>>> check = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
>>> checkIfExists(check)
Input new number:
6
return new check:
['2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
>>> checkIfExists(check)
Input new number:
7
return new check:
['3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you move the input() outside the function it's easier to communicate the problem:

```
def checkIfExists(list, var):
    if var not in list:
        # assumes list is not empty
        list.pop(0)
        list.append(var)
    return list

check = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
for var in ['6', '7']:
    check = checkIfExists(check, var)
    print(check)
```

Will give you this output:

```
['2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
['3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
```